# Which preposition comes in the phrase "assistant professor in English"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which preposition should I use in the sentence "He is an assistant professor in English" or should i use "He is an assistant professor of English"?

Comment: Related: *[Graduate student in or of?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/153459)*

Answer (score 1):

Look at the examples in this [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Professor%20of,%20professor%20in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,Professor%20of;,c0;.t1;,professor%20in;,c0) comparison and you'll find 'of' generally relates to a subject area, and 'in' to a place.

In the example you gave, unless for some reason the person was in a room called or referred to as 'English', 'of' is the correct preposition to use.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this. The question is unbelievably trivial, in that OP could just as easily have compared Google search results himself, and there's no significant reason apart from "established idiomatic preference" why one preposition is more "correct" than the other. All I can think is that the downvoter thought you could have made the preference more obvious by graphing **Professor of/in English** (where **in** effectively "flatlines", it's so rare).

Answer (score 0):

Should be,

> He is an assistant professor of English Literature

While `in` can be use in below scenario,

> He got a Nobel Prize in English Literature

Answer (score 0):

He is an assistant professor of English Literature 
or
He is an assistant professor of English

Of preposition usage - who/what does it belong to, what does it show