# Graduate student in or of?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

In my cover letter I want to write that I am a graduate student in statistics. But I am not sure about the "in". So what is correct?

> I am a graduate student in statistics.
>
> I am a graduate student of statistics.

Comment: You could use a gerund instead of a preposition: _I am a graduate student studying statistics_.

Comment: @J.R. Although many wouldn't class that particular -ing form usage as a 'gerund'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say *in* Statistics.

The reason I say this is because you would say:  I am majoring *in* Statistics.

Or in response to the question:  What do you do for a living?  You might say, "I'm *in* plastics."

You can say I'm a student *of* Statistics, and hence, it wouldn't be wrong to say graduate student *of* Statistics.  But, I don't believe it is the common usage (in American English).

Comment: In Britain we do not 'major' in things. As undergraduates we 'read' subjects. Even a chemist, spending 75% of their time in a laboratory, would be 'reading' chemistry. At least that was always the case but younger people may well tell me I'm wrong. For that reason I would say 'I am a post-graduate student of statistics'.

Comment: @WS2 I think younger people will tell you you are wrong sir, respectfully.

Comment: @ws2 You'll note that I did make it clear that this was the American English usage in my post. And, in that context it is 100% correct.

Comment: @d'alar'cop I should just mention to you that although later this year I shall enter my eighth decade, I took a 3 year undergraduate degree as recently as 2002-5, and a masters immediately thereafter, at the University of Reading. I was given no special favours and mingled with 18-22 year-olds at lectures and seminars every day. So, you will understand, I am not entirely out of touch on these matters.

Comment: @WS2 what are you studying?  I always find if fascinating when older people go back for advanced degrees. (I've always had a fantasy of pursuing a PhD in my retirement years)

Comment: @DavidM History. (If you look at my profile on this site it tells you all about me). I was tempted but drew the line at doing a PhD for two reasons. First it is too much like real work. And I am supposed to be retired! Second, research is not as much fun as an undergrad degree. You tend to work alone on a very specific topic. My enjoyment of history comes from wide reading and engaging with the cut and thrust of argument with others!

Comment: @WS2 That makes perfect sense to me.  I myself already have a degree in Medicine.  So, it would seem that I should be shooting for a PhD.  I also, in my daydreams, consider pursuing a JD.  (That's what we call a law school degree here in the states.)

Answer (score 4):

In Britain we do not 'major' in things.

As undergraduates we 'read' subjects. Even a chemist, spending 75% of their time in a laboratory, would be 'reading' chemistry.

At least that was always the case but younger people may well tell me I'm wrong.

For that reason I would say 'I am a post-graduate student of statistics'.

Answer (score 0):

Only capitalize it if it's a major. AP would say no to this-- only if it's a language (French, English), but for your purposes it would be OK.

Otherwise, give your major first and then say you're specializing in statistics. Don't capitalize it.

Answer (score 0):

I am an university student studying at Australia. Personally, i think you can say in this way:" I am a graduate student with major in statistics."

Comment: You study AT Australia? Is it the name of a university?

Comment: Sorry, never heard of it...why?

Comment: Normally, if I refer to a continent  or a  country, I'd say IN. I live IN Italy, I travel IN Europe.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. A native speaker would usually insert an article before *major*: *I am a graduate student with a major in statistics* or *I am a graduate student majoring in statistics.* But note also that terms like *major* or *concentration* are not used in every program or in every country, which may be why the OP has asked for a more generic association.

Answer (score 0):

I (British English native speaker) wouldn't use either of your example sentences; they sound wrong to me.

There is a phrase in English "student of xyz" which would be valid, meaning "studying xyz", i.e. I'd use "of" rather than "in" for the subject. But I wouldn't use that for "graduate student", because I parse that as "I am graduate studying xyz" which makes no sense.

As another example, I'd have no problems with someone being described as a "director of HR", or someone having the job title "Technical Director", but it doesn't sound right to say "Technical Director of HR".

Another alternative for how you could phrase it is "graduate student in the xyz department".

Answer (score -2):

You can say ''I am a graduate student at XYZ majoring statistics''

Comment: OP is looking for the correct proposition to use.  Either by accident or on purpose your response omits the preposition altogether which makes it ungrammatical.